Problem with my external monitor when suspending
I use ubuntu 22.04 on a laptop and I have a problem with my external monitor. After suspending my ubuntu and switching it back on, the screen of my external monitor freezes. This has been happening unfrequently, but now it always happens whenever my Ubuntu suspends.Does anybody knows how to fix it?

what is your specific question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

Do you have an Nvidia GPU by any chance ?
I've had terrible experience with them: every time they suspend, the gpu wackes up all sideways: it reports that it does not support cuda or toher stuff like that. Also, I found USB-c output to be much buggier than hdmi: can't say if it's true, because of the intermitent nature of the problem.

Yes, and I have cuda installed by the way. But the only problem I have is with the external monitor. Also, I use hdmi. So far, it has frozen very unfrequently, but since 2 weeks ago, it happens every time Ubuntu suspends
